# Optionally create new items in unmanaged package

Tags: package, unmanaged-package, package-install, professional-edition

I'm trying to create an unmanaged package that makes some modifications to Lead Layout, but it still includes "LogACall" and other actions that are standard in many orgs.

I would like installing the package to succeed even if the org has these already, and to just use the ones they already have, but when I try to install the package I get the error

> The name "LogACall" is already used on component type: Action. Please rename existing component.

Is there any way to do this?  I'm trying to create the package with the UI, but I'm open to other ways of creating a package.  When I analyze the package on the package link, it says "This is a brand new component," even though I don't want it to be, but I'm not sure how to change that.

Edit: this is for Professional edition.

Answer (score 2):

Unmanaged Packages have this problem. What you're looking for is an [Unlocked Package](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_unlocked_pkg_intro.htm). Unlocked Packages, as opposed to Unmanaged Packages, will happily merge with existing metadata. Be aware that the contents of an org that match the Unlocked Package's content will be overwritten, so some caution is advised when installing Unlocked Packages. However, this is way to go, especially for subscribers looking to simplify their metadata deployment experience. Also, Unmanaged Packages **cannot be upgraded**, so it's a lot more useful to create Unlocked Packages for long-term development.

Comment: Thanks!  I just edited my question to specify that I was looking for a solution for professional edition, and my understanding was unlocked need enterprise+.  Thoughts?

Comment: @Kat Even if, for whatever reason, you can't use production as the Dev Hub, you can create a Developer Edition to create your Second Generation Packages and install them from there.

Comment: Okay, I got this working, and I'm able to add new layouts with an Unlocked package, but I still can't modify the built-in Lead Layout.  I think that might just be the way it is, but I still can't find any documentation that explicitly confirms that

Comment: @Kat Correct. Page Layouts don't upgrade when you upgrade a package. Some manual configuration is required.